# xUnit test with callback (other thread) swallows exceptions

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, xunit

I got an xUnit test which does some checks one a propietary TCP protocol implementation. The test launches a mocked server which is instructed to send the consumer in the unit test some data it should process:

```
[Fact]
public async void EmptyList()
{
    string rawMessage = ...

    MockServer server = new MockServer();
    server.Start();

    ManualResetEvent messageReceived = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        using (var cn = new Connection())
        {
            cn.MessageReceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                var m = e.Message;
                Assert.Equal<CommandId>(CommandId.Command1, m.CommandId);
                var l = m.GetList<int>("Users");
                Assert.Equal(0, l.Count);
                var emptyDict = m.GetComplexData<string>("EmptyComplex");
                Assert.Equal(0, emptyDict.Count);
                messageReceived.Set();
            };
            await cn.ConnectAsync(server.Hostname, server.Port, tokenSource.Token);
            var receiveTask = cn.Receive(tokenSource.Token);
            server.SendMessageToAll(rawMessage); // mock server send the connected client some sample data

            messageReceived.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            Assert.False(receiveTask.IsFaulted); // [[A]]
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}
```

When one of the asserts in the message handler `MessageReceived` fails, it does not give the proper error message. The console shows it caused a `ThreadAbortException`. In fact before inserting the line marked with **A** the test even completed as a success ignoring the error from the message handler.

So how can I change this that I get proper error message like *Does not match expected...*? Is there a way the errors in the other thread (here in `receiveTask`) are handled a proper unit test failures?

Would

```
if (receiveTask.Exception != null) throw receiveTask.Exception;
```

be the proper way?

Also I noted that when I use `try-finally` inside `MessageReceived` so that the test must not wait for the full timeout (`messageReceived.Set()`) the task itself does not get to faulted and does not have an exception. So I am not sure this is a reliable way to do this.

Comment: The test is mixing async and blocking calls. The exception is swallowed because test method is `async void` change test to `async Task` and remove blocking calls. Refactor the test to be async all the way through.

Comment: @Nkosi Hm, not sure how to do that. The code blocks because it takes some time  to have the mock server send the TCP/IP packets to the loopback and have the event handler handle that event. I do not see how I could wait for the event with the help of a `Task`.